# Intersection/Feasibility control of 3 dimensional vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have a 3-dimensional vector with multiple tuples (elements):

```
coverFeasible[d][y1].push_back(colIdx)
```

For a given d and y1, I want to check whether any element (coverFeasible[d][y1][r1]) is also an element of coverFeasible[d][y1'] where y1' is the rest of the set (all others out of y1).

More precisely, I keep the track of all possible feasibility where one element of the first is not an element of second (all combinations of y1). And, I want to do this control for all possible d values.

If there is no common elements between coverFeasible[d][y1] and coverFeasible[d][y1'], then I want to keep this, and I try to obtain minimum of a parameter in all feasible lists in respect to coverFeasible[d][y1].

I did a try with a lot-of for loops. But, the results is not matching on what I want:

```
for (int d=1 ; d<=n; d++){
    min_feasible_LB_cost[d]=1000; //A Large value
  for (int y1=1; y1<= (qc)*(n)*(sp)*tt; y1++){   //Until all y1s are covered
      for (int y2=y1+1; y2<= (qc)*(n)*(sp)*tt; y2++){
              bool gotoMainLoop = false;
          for (int r1=1; r1 <= coverFeasible[d][y1].size(); r1++){
              for(int r2=1; r2<= coverFeasible[d][y2].size(); r2++){
                  if(coverFeasible[d][y1][r1]==coverFeasible[d][y2][r2])
                      gotoMainLoop = true;
                 else {if(lowerbound_totalcolCost[d][y2] <= min_feasible_LB_cost[d] )  
                       min_feasible_LB_cost[d]=lowerbound_totalcolCost[d][y2];
                     else
                         min_feasible_LB_cost[d]=min_feasible_LB_cost[d];}}}
          break;}
      }
}
```

I can try some intersection of vectors however I don't know how to do that with two-dimensional vectors.

I would like to have your advises which would help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a `std::set` instead of a vector for `coverFeasible[d][y1]` and then you could use [set intersection from the std library.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)